# Angular formio custom component

Tags: angular, formio

i've followed formio docs to create custom component but i'm just a beginner so i can't get it work. i want to create custom component to achieve this page

[image]

i want to create custom component like add new card which you can choose the children of that card, such as video, or images, inputs etc. basically i want to achieve google forms builder i found formio is the best choice for form builder but i got stuck with this custom component. i heard someone have finally create custom component here in stackoverflow, i also ask them in their question. So, anyone can help me with this? maybe you have source code for me to follow, or anything, really appreciate any help

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i've created a component based on this https://github.com/formio/angular-demo/blob/master/src/app/components/CheckMatrix.js but always gives me an error. i've read a doc for https://github.com/merobal/angular-formio-custom-demo too but i don't understand cause my knowledge is not that far

Comment: i've done it, but now i need new properties for my component, do you know how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097505/add-custom-properties-on-formio-builder

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing this successfully for a while.

First, find an existing component in Formio that does something close to what you want. If your new element just presents something non-interactive, then you an go with an 'HTML' component.

This is the code you need:

```
var htmlComponent = Formio.Components.components.htmlelement; // or whatever
class MyNewComponent extends htmlComponent{

  static schema(...extend) {
    return super.schema({
          type: 'MyNewComponent',
          label: "The Default Label",
          any_other_fields: "",
    }, ...extend);

    static get builderInfo() {
      return {
        title: 'Name in the Builder',
        group: 'custom',
        icon: 'picture-o',
        weight: 5,
        schema: this.schema()
      };
    }

    render(element) {
      // Here's where you add your HTML to get put up.
      // 
      tpl += "<div ref='myref'>Hi there!</div>";
      // Note the use of the 'ref' tag, which is used later to find 
      // parts of your rendered element.
      
      // If you need to render the superclass,
      // you can do that with 
      // tpl+=super.render(element);

      // This wraps your template to give it the standard label and bulider decorations         
      return Formio.Components.components.component.prototype.render.call(this,tpl);

    }
    
    attach(element) {
      // This code is called after rendering, when the DOM has been created.
      // You can find your elements above like this:
      this.loadRefs(element, {myref: 'single'});

      var superattach = super.attach(element);
       // Here do whatever you need to attach event handlers to the dom.
      this.refs.myref.on('click',()=>{alert("hi!");});                    

      return superattach;
    }
    
    getvalue() {
      return 3; // the value this element puts into the form
    }
    // OR, depending on which component type you're basing on:
    getValueAt(index,value,flags) {}

    setValue(value) {
      // modify your DOM here to reflect that the value should be 'value'.
    };
    // OR, depending on what component type:
    getValueAt(index) {}

  }
  
  // This sets the form that pops up in the Builder when you create
  // one of these.  It is basically just a standard form, and you
  // can look at the contents of this in the debugger.
  MyNewComponent.editForm = htmlComponent.editForm;


  // Register your component to Formio
  Formio.Components.addComponent('MyNewComponent', MyNewComponent);
```

This was hard-won knowledge; hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Thats great! i've followed from their docs, i want to create something that interactive and i can't make it work, so i don't use it anymore i create something similar to google form from scratch, thanks for your aswer though it's really great

Comment: This is a great answer as it explains what formio's custom components but i cant seem to find the Formio.Components in the latest formio version, did they change something? "@formio/angular": "^5.1.1" "formiojs": "^4.13.4"...and i am using formio's angular implementation too.

Comment: @teh_ouh: I'm not sure about the Angular version; likely they wrapped the Formio namespace up a little differently. In plain javascript, Formio is a global namespace.