# Add custom properties on formio builder

Tags: angular, formio

I want to create something like this

[image]

I want to create a card which contains tags such as pharagraph, iframe, also inputs. I have successfully added custom component to my form builder but i need to pass a property for my new component. like, i have a component for iframe, but i need to pass a url to that component, anyone know how?

Here's my codefor one of the component

```
<div style="width: 100%;margin-top: 20px;">
          <nb-card>
            <nb-card-body class="myIframe">
              <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gSfc4GhlZ44" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen
                mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </nb-card-body>
          </nb-card>
        </div>
```

i want that iframe src to be dynamic and users can insert their url to that property. i appreciate any help

EDIT

Here's my builder html code

```
    <form-builder [form]="form" (change)="onChange($event)"></form-builder>
<div class="well jsonviewer">
    <pre id="json"><code class="language-json" #json></code></pre>
</div>
```

and builder.ts

```
export class StepBuilderComponent {

  @ViewChild('json', {static: false}) jsonElement?: ElementRef;
  public form: Object = {
    components: []
  };
  onChange(event) {
    this.jsonElement.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';
    this.jsonElement.nativeElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(event.form, null, 4)));
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you add form code here?

Comment: do you mean form builder code?

Comment: it's just like this <form-builder [form]="form" (change)="onChange($event)"></form-builder>

Comment: or maybe i don't have to use formio, do you know any angular package to achieve that? i've use ng2-surveys and angular-survey but i can't make it work the way i wanted

Comment: so you can add an extra control in your form and assign url as value e.g. iFrameUrl: ['url']

Comment: yes but how to add that extra control in formio?

Comment: You can pass json to your formio element which you already have. You can add an extra element in that json.

Comment: i use basic component from formio, and i don't know how to create custom formbuilder, in the docs they only show it on angularjs, i'm angular 8

Comment: Add your html in your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211205/discussion-between-gourav-garg-and-naoval).